# I want to update table by changing in another table using EF

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in SQL, and the tables are related based on `ID`. I want to update the second table (automatically) when the first table is updated.

First table columns:

```
SYSID    FoodName    FoodPrice
```

Second table columns:

```
SYSID   FoodID   FoodName   FoodUnitPrice   FoodSahm   FoodPrice
```

Now my problem: when `FoodPrice` changes in the first table, then `FoodUnitPrice` needs to be updated in the second table automatically.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Please share what you have tried until now. You can edit your question to include the code.

Comment: That's not something you can do in EF -  **if** you can do it, it will be a trigger - but triggers are highly vendor-specific so you'll need to tell us by adding a tag which **RDBMS** you're using (since *SQL* is only the query language - used by almost all RDBMS - that doesn't tell us whether you're using `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, `mysql` or `postgresql`)

Comment: You may want to normalize your tables so you don't have to do update in multiple tables. In some cases normalization may not be appropriate but then you would know this and internationally you wouldn't normalize it further.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to do anything on your project. Just create a trigger on sql server that updates FoodUnitPrice field when FoodPrice changes.